# MySQL: aggregate data, aggregate the same data under a condition, then check if equal and save in result set

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries that I'd like to compare the result against.

`SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM form  GROUP BY person_id;`

`SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM form WHERE status IS NULL GROUP BY person_id;`

If both results are equal, then I'd like to display it. Otherwise I don't, since I'm interested in the results of users that are only have NULL results as a status and not 1 or more complete statuses.

So as an example, let's say there are 3 users.

User 1 only has statuses that are non `NULL`.

User 2 has 3 statuses that are `NULL` and 3 that are non `NULL`.

User 3 has 6 statuses that are `NULL`.

Then whatd I'd like the get is the complete row of user 3.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` clause with a `CASE EXPRESSION`:

```
SELECT person_id,count(*) as cnt FROM form t
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 1 END)
```

Comment: Thanks, I double checked it against the data and this is exactly what I needed. I never heard of the `CASE` expression before.